# With the Haskell graphics library Gloss, is it possible to mask a picture to only display in a certain extent (ie within a rectangle)

Tags: haskell, graphics

I have been using the [Gloss Library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gloss-1.7.4.1) for some game programming, and have got to the point where I am having the most difficulty laying out different elements on the screen. I was wondering whether it was possible to limit a `Picture` type to display only a certain rectangular area of the screen. The library already has the concept of a rectangular area with the `Extent` type, but there does not appear to be any way to 'subtract' from pictures.

If there was a way of doing this then it seems like creating a `View` type or similar that takes over responsibility for a certain area of the screen — which can also contain additional views, and with suitable coordinate substitutions between them etc — would be an achievable and sensible goal. But without a way to limit drawing areas it doesn't seem like this would be possible within the Gloss framework.

Comment: I don’t believe so (but hard to justify this in a proper answer). BTW, a common term for this is clipping.

Comment: While it doesn't look like gloss lets you do this directly, you should be able easily emulate it by constructing a "frame" shape and overlaying the frame onto the picture you want to limit the size of.

Comment: Clipping! Knew there was a word! If it were just one picture I wanted to clip then yes, it could be placed within a background coloured frame. But if you want a clipped picture *inside* another, then the framing technique will not work, at least I can't think how it would.

It is a shame, because Gloss is so easy to use, and in every other way has everything I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that clipping is not supported in Gloss.

Nevertheless the recursive drawing of views each with their own relative coordinate system does still seem to be a viable and useful goal, and I am part way through writing code for this now.